# SQL query select

Tags: sql-server

I am using MSSQL Server and Nodejs with npm mssql. I need to build a query.

**Explanation**:
Need to select Users from table that did not receive emails today or never receive.

*Query example:*

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Users u 
LEFT JOIN dbo.userEmailHistory ueh 
ON u.id = ueh.userId 
WHERE IsNull(sDate, '') = '' 
OR CONVERT(date,sDate)>=CONVERT(date,DATEADD(day,1,getdate()))
```

**Then:**
Need to select the user favorite brand. I am doing async. So the code is looking like this:

```
    function getUserSalesByMalls(params, callback) {
      var usersArray = [];
      var targetID = params.type;
      async.eachLimit(params, 1, function (user, cb) {
          sqlRequest("
SELECT TOP 1 bts.BrandCategoryID as title, b.title as brand, b.id 
FROM dbo.Users st JOIN SaleView ss ON (st.ID=ss.userID) 
JOIN Sales sa ON (sa.ID=ss.SaleID) 
JOIN Brands b ON (b.ID=sa.BrandID) 
JOIN KEY_BrandcategoryToSale bts ON (bts.SaleID=sa.ID) 
WHERE st.ID="+**user.id**+" 
GROUP BY bts.BrandCategoryID, b.title, b.id 
ORDER BY COUNT(bts.BrandCategoryID) desc", 
function (err, result) {
              user.favBrand = result;
              console.log(user);
              usersArray.push(user);
              cb();
          })
      }, function () {
        callback(null, usersArray)
      })
    }
```

**Then:**
I need to select top 2 sales by user favorite brand that were most viewed in period 14 days and user never seen it:

```
    function getUserSalesByMalls(params, callback) {
              var usersArray = [];
              var targetID = params.type;
              async.eachLimit(params, 1, function (user, cb) {
                  sqlRequest("
        `SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 s.id as saleId, s.title, s.description, s.imageUrl, count(sv.saleId) as mostViewsPeriod14Days, s.guid, stm.mallId as mallId, brand.title as brandTitle FROM dbo.Sales s 
INNER JOIN dbo.SalesToMall stm ON s.id = stm.saleId 
INNER JOIN dbo.SaleView sv ON s.id = sv.saleId 
INNER JOIN dbo.Brands brand ON s.brandID = brand.id 
WHERE (sv.date <= GETDATE()) 
AND (sv.date >= GETDATE() - 14) AND s.isActive = 1 AND s.isHotSale = 1 AND b.id = "+user.favBrandId+" 
AND s.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT sv2.saleId FROM dbo.SaleView sv2 
WHERE sv2.userId = "+user.id+") 
GROUP BY s.id, s.title, s.description, s.imageUrl, s.guid, stm.mallId, brand.title 
ORDER BY COUNT(sv.saleId) DESC`", 
        function (err, result) {
                      user.salesByBrand = result;
                      console.log(user);
                      usersArray.push(user);
                      cb();
                  })
              }, function () {
                callback(null, usersArray)
              })
            }
```

**And then** **last one**: i need to select 3 suggestions for the user by mall id that were most viewed in period 14 days and user never seen it:

```
    function getUserSalesByMalls(params, callback) {
      var usersArray = [];
      var targetID = params.type;
      async.eachLimit(params, requestPerLimit, function (user, cb) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          sqlRequest("SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 s.id as saleId, s.title, s.description, s.imageUrl, count(sv.saleId) as mostViewsPeriod14Days, s.guid, stm.mallId as mallId, brand.title as brandTitle 
FROM dbo.Sales s 
INNER JOIN dbo.SalesToMall stm ON s.id = stm.saleId 
INNER JOIN dbo.SaleView sv ON s.id = sv.saleId 
INNER JOIN dbo.Brands brand ON s.brandID = brand.id 
WHERE (sv.date <= GETDATE()) 
AND (sv.date >= GETDATE() - 14) 
AND s.isActive = 1 AND s.isHotSale = 1 
AND stm.mallId = "+user.mallId+" 
AND s.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT sv2.saleId 
FROM dbo.SaleView sv2 
WHERE sv2.userId = "+user.id+") 
GROUP BY s.id, s.title, s.description, s.imageUrl, s.guid, stm.mallId, brand.title 
ORDER BY COUNT(sv.saleId) DESC", function (err, result) {
            if (!result) {
              cb();
            } else if (result.length == 3) {
              sqlInsert("INSERT INTO UserEmailHistory (userID,sDate,targetID) VALUES (" + user.id + ",CONVERT(datetime,DATEADD(hour," + utc_diff + ",getdate()))," + targetID + ")");
              console.log("USER WITH 3 SALES BY MALL");
              user.sales = result;
              console.log(user);
              usersArray.push(user);
              cb();
            }
          })
        }, requestPerMillisecond)
      }, function () {
        callback(null, usersArray)
      })
    }
```

**My question is:**
Is there any way to combine and build only one query and get all necessary data regarding my explanation?

Comment: see the link referenced to know on , how to improve question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You really need to improve your question.